# Return arrays object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array with objects inside of it.

```
var obj1 = [
 user1 = {
  "name" : "John",
  "age" : 24,
  "city" : "London"
 },
 user2 = {
  "name" : "Jane",
  "age" : 22,
  "city" : "New York",
 }
];
```

Now what I would like to do is to get name of the objects inside the array so in this case it would be "user1" and "user2".

**FIRST TRY**

At first I tried doing it like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++){
 document.getElementById('app').innerHTML += obj1[i];
}
```

And the outcome is `[object Object][object Object]`

**SECOND TRY**

So then I tried to use `JSON.strigify` on the objects, but then it returns the whole object and not it's name as I would like to:

```
for(i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++){
 document.getElementById('app').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj1[i]);
}
```

Outcome:

```
{"name":"John","age":24,"city":"London"}{"name":"Jane","age":22,"city":"New York"}
```

**QUESTION**

Is it possible, and if yes how should I go about displaying names of all of the objects inside of an array, but not displaying their content.
Desired outcome:

```
user1 user2
```

Comment: Re First Try: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/cuyedotisu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: please add valid objects.

Comment: Re Second Try: That's identical to the First Try

Comment: @Quentin you were right sorry, pasted wrong code line

Comment: @NinaScholz — The objects are valid

Comment: Let check this one for array assign https://jsfiddle.net/bs7dbja1/ , but it better to use for object assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code does:

1. Create an object
2. Implicitly create a global variable called `user1` and assign that object to it
3. Create another object
4. Implicitly create a global variable called `user2` and assign that object to it
5. Create an array
6. Populate the array with the values of the variables `user1` and `user2`
7. Create a local variable called `obj1` and assign the array to it

The array knows **nothing** about the variables `user1` and `user2`. They were just the source of the data copied into it.

The objects know **nothing** about the variables `user1` and `user2`. Relationships in JavaScript are unidirectional. A variable can refer to an object (in fact, multiple variables can refer to the same object) but there is no way to backtrack.

> Now what I would like to do is to get name of the objects inside the array so in this case it would be "user1" and "user2".

You can't.

(Well, not without doing horrible guesswork like looping over every global variable (property of the `window` object, browser JS only) and comparing it to the object … and if you are going down that route then you need to redesign your code to achieve your real goal in a more sensible way).

Comment: So let me clarify if I'm getting your answer right. The problem was with my flawed perception of how arrays of objects should be created. The "user1" and "user2" are variables which are completly redundant in this case because I cannot access their names the way i wanted?

Comment: @MateuszJuruś — Yes.